# HTTPS Authentication in clojure

Tags: clojure

A have an application which parses an xml from a static url.  The applciation worked up until recently when they updated the access to the URL.  It is now required to input an NT username/password.

I am struggling to do this as I cannot install any extra libraries other than the ones provided, one of which is not clj-http.  Is there any other way around this in clojure?  How would I use java.org.apachehttpclient for example?

```
(ns Summary
(:import [java.net URL])
(:use [clojure.java.io :only [input-stream]])
(:require [clojure.xml :as xml])  
(:require [clojure.zip :as zip])  
(:require [clojure.contrib.zip-filter.xml :as zf]))  



(defn get-field [element child]
(zf/xml1-> element child zf/text))

(defn parse-record [rec-xml]
(into {}
    (map 
        #(vector % (get-field rec-xml %))
        [:sys_id :sys_updated ])))


(defn get-records [xml]
(map 
    parse-record
    (zf/xml-> (zip/xml-zip xml)
              :Record                                
              )))
(def viewDoc 
(with-open [is (input-stream      (URL. "https://www.test.com" "Domain/username" "password"))]
    (let [recs (doall (get-records (xml/parse is)))]


)
))
```

Comment: "It is now required to input an NT username/password" - are you talking about basic authentication, or?

Comment: No, it is NTLM authentication, windows - domain/username and password

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html) should get you going. Should be easy to convert to Clojure.